# float element to top right corner of fieldset

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to take this box that I have floating on the right side of a div, and make it so that it is flush with the top-right corner? I have tried making it `position:relative` and `top:0px`, but it stubbornly remains offset by the padding of the legend.

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/dpUM2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to set the position to `absolute`, or set the `#title` element to `float:left`.

Example with `position:absolute` on #top and `position:relative` on #out:

http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/dpUM2/9/

Example with #title set to `float:left`:

http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/dpUM2/13/

Answer (score 1):

Position:relative on the parent, position:absolute on the child, notice the -1px to make it overlap the border of the parent.

```
#out{
width:300px;
height:400px;
background:#efefef;   
border:1px solid gray;   
position:relative;
}
#top{
top:0;
right:-1px;
background-color:#fff;
width:150px;
height:25px;
border:1px solid black;
position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/dpUM2/14/

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to be as follows:

```
#out{
        width:300px;
    height:400px;
     background:#efefef;   
         border:1px solid gray;
    padding:0px;    
    }
    #top{
     float:right;   
        background-color:#fff;
        width:150px;
        height:25px;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin:0px;
    }
    #title{
     padding:0px; 
        margin:0px;
        float:left;

    }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `#top`:

```
position: relative;
top: -24px;
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dpUM2/10/